# Vue request fails but does not log errors

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I have this add method in my vue script

```
if (this.edit === false) {
     this.link.link = submitEvent.target.elements.link.value;
     fetch('products', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(this.link),
          headers: {
             'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
       })
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(res => {                    // this does not get executed
             this.qrcode.redirect_url = ""; 
             alert('Added');
             this.fetchAll()
       })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.res));
   }
}
```

When I fill the form the request is send and entry is made to the database but I do not get response.
I am using laravel as backend and Add method in Controller returns 200 response after creation.
What could cause it and why `console.log(err)` does not not display anything?

Comment: Hi, is the server sending any response body?

Comment: @Nora the res variable is undefined

Comment: Now I am completely lost, getting response from localhost/login, when I send request to localhost/products

Comment: In network `/products` gives status `302` and redirect to `/login`